# Blender Alters .Obj vertex list

Tags: python, mesh, bmesh

I have a wavefront .obj file and a sharp edge list which are mapped with the vertex index form the .obj file. Now I want to add some functionality in the .obj file based on the sharp edge list. But the problem is when I load the .obj file in blender, blender changes the vertex index. So I can not map the same edge list from the .obj file in Blender. Is there a way I can prevent Blender from changing the vertex index and keep them same as the original .obj file(e.g. in .obj file, vertex index starts from 1 and the index increases by one for each subsequent vertex)? I am wondering why Blender has to change the original vertex index rather than giving the index sequentially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an option for **Keep Vertex Order** in the .obj importer. Use that and you should be fine.

[image]